# Is the Commonwealth restored in Andromeda?

Tags: andromeda

The driving motivation for the main character in [*Andromeda*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_%28TV_series%29) was to seek the restoration of the [All Systems Commonwealth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Commonwealth).  The Commonwealth, which is mostly a facsimile of Star Trek's Federation, fell when it was betrayed from within by genetically engineered humans called [Nietzscheans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nietzschean_%28Andromeda%29).

In the TV series, the Commonwealth is restored at the end of [season two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_%28TV_series%29#Season_two). How does this compare with [Robert Hewitt Wolfe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Hewitt_Wolfe)'s original plans? In particular, does his one-act play mention the fate of the Commonwealth?

Comment: The wikipedia article you link to answers this question.

Comment: The story had two endings because the series creator had laid out his plans for the end in a play, but had gotten fired before he was allowed to execute.  The produces took the show in the opposite direction.  If you read the wikipedia material for the show it is somewhat sparse.  I was hoping to get an interpretation from someone who has actually seen the show.  Therefore, I request that you please reopen the question.

Comment: “In season four, Dylan is nearly outlawed by the Systems Commonwealth he himself had restored.” How does that not answer your question? (I'm trying to decide whether to reopen or delete this question.)

Comment: @Gilles: It seems like an legit question these days.  And yeah that's a decent answer.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question to concentrate on what Wikipedia doesn't answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the one-act play, [Coda](http://www.cyberspace5.net/agentrichard07/coda.pdf), Trance and Harper discuss possible futures. In the Perfect Possible Future she describes, the Commonwealth is indeed restored - there are also three other great empires (the Nietzscheans, the Wayists, and the Consensus of Parts).

Trance doesn't like this version of the future, so she describes an alternative, which also features the restored Commonwealth. I believe it's this version of the future that we would have eventually seen if Wolfe had continued.

However, the play is actually just Trance considering how to proceed (as we see in other episodes, although not normally talking to anyone else). It doesn't actually confirm which path she decides to lead everyone down.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this](http://andromeda.wikia.com/wiki/Systems_Commonwealth#The_Restored_Systems_Commonwealth) source the Systems Commonwealth was restored by Dylan and his crew in the second year of their mission as the threat from Magog became known. They had successfully ratified a new Systems Commonwealth with at least 50 member worlds and a new High Guard.

However it was later betrayed (once again) by Nietzscheans and was plagued by civil wars. Also same source says;

> However, the Restored Systems Commonwealth seems to be a regressive, twisted form of the Commonwealth: the direct antithesis of what the Commonwealth should be like.